# Use array for images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have to make an array with images in them and then check if another image collides with them.

So far I have try'd:

```
NSMutableArray *platforms = [NSMutableArray array];
[platforms addObject:platform1];
[platforms addObject:platform2];
[platforms addObject:platform3];
[platforms addObject:platform4];
[platforms addObject:platform5];
[platforms addObject:platform6];
[platforms addObject:platform7];
[platforms addObject:platform8];
for (platforms in platforms) << code not working needs to do this for the amount of platforms in the array
{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platforms.frame))
    {

    }
}
```

Though this code does not work.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by collides with them, you mean overlap on the screen or the content (actual image) is similar or the same?

Comment: `for (platforms in platforms)` Are you sure that you properly use iteration?

Comment: Does this really compile: `for (platforms in platforms)`?

Comment: With collide i simply mean if they intersect like the code say's but that is not my problem the problem is that the array is not working.

Comment: @SeniorMe: You need to add imageViews to array not images

Comment: How do you mean? how do i add imageviews in stead of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your array consists of `UIImages`. You need to add `UIImageViews` for implementing such a task.

There is no frame property for `UIImage`.
Add the `UIImageViews` instead of the `UIImage`.

And change the code like:

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in platforms)
{
   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, imgView.frame))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are adding the images ? the image views in which the images are adding, add that imageViews to array. Instead of image.

Comment: I tried this answer and it worked pretty well, I got another small question, is there a way to let a code go off if not one time the if in the for loop is accepted?

Comment: @SeniorMe: yes, just put a `break;` in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id platform in platforms) {
...
}
```

Or use:

```
for (id theObject in platforms) {
    if(theObject isKindOfClass[UIImage class]) {
        UIImage *theImage = (UIImage*) theObject; 
       //do something with the image 
    }
}
```

Plus - you did not initialize your array. Use:

```
NSMutableArray *platforms = [[NSMutableArray array] initWithCapacity:8];
```

or at least:

```
NSMutableArray *platforms = [[NSMutableArray array] init];
```

The 8 given for the capacity during initialization does not need to be the exact number nor the maximum number of objects. It is just a (minor) preformance gain when the number matches or is just slightgly higher than the actual maximum number of objects in the array.

Comment: UIImage *platform in platforms gives me the error:"Collection expression type "UIImage *" may not respond to "countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count"

Comment: There is no frame property for `UIImage`

Comment: All right then use id in the enumeration and test it for beeing a proper UIImage object withtin the loop body. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ([platforms containsObject:@"platforms1"]) {
NSLog(@"the object selection is contained in array");
}
else{
NSLog(@"not contain");
}
```